# Blazor - how to remove a child component

Tags: blazor, blazor-component

**BackGround**

I have a component `MainComponent` with multiple buttons which will make a new `SubComponent` appear (`<TaskList AreaId="@SelectedAreaId" IsVisible="@IsVisible"></TaskList>`).

**Problem**

The problem appears when I wanted to put a close button on the `SubComponent`: I tried creating a button on it and make: `IsVisible = !IsVisible`. While this does work to some extent (it makes the component disappear from the view), it has the problem that if I click on the button from `MainComponent` with the same `SubComponent` it will not appear (I assume because the component is still "alive").

What's the best solution to this? I was thinking of using `IDisposable` on the `SubComponent`, but `ComponentName.Dispose()` is not defined.

**Edit1:** Added example of what I'm currently doing

**MainComponent** (TaskList.razor)

```
    <div class="col-12 outer-div row">
        <TaskDetails TaskId="@SelectedTaskId" IsVisible="@IsTaskDetailsVisible"></TaskDetails>
    </div>
    ...
            <ul>
                @for (int i = 0; i < MondayTasks.Count(); i++)
                {
                    var myIndex = i;
                    <li class="btn" @onclick="@(() => LoadTaskDetailsForTask(MondayTasks[myIndex].Id))">
                        <a role="button">
                            <h4>@MondayTasks[i].Name</h4>
                            <p>@MondayTasks[i].DeadlineDate.Date.ToShortDateString()</p>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                }
            </ul>
    ...

private async Task LoadTaskDetailsForTask(int taskId)
{
    SelectedTaskId = taskId;
    IsTaskDetailsVisible = true;
    await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("onScrollEvent");
}
```

**SubComponent** (TaskDetails.razor)

```
@if (IsVisible)
{
    ...
            <div class="row">
                <h2 class="inner-div title">@taskDetails.Name</h2>
                <span class="closebtn" @onclick="()=> ToggleVisibility()">&times;</span>
            </div>

    //Display Information
}

...
protected async override void OnParametersSet()
{
    taskDetails = await _dbTasks.GetTasksDetails(TaskId);
    TaskItems = await _dbTasks.GetTasksItems(TaskId);
    this.StateHasChanged();
}

private void ToggleVisibility()
{
    IsVisible = !IsVisible;
}
```

**Edit2:** Added Working Code

**MainComponent** (TaskList.razor)

```
    <CascadingValue Value="this">
    <div class="col-12 outer-div row">
        <TaskDetails TaskId="@SelectedTaskId" IsVisible="@IsTaskDetailsVisible"></TaskDetails>
    </div>
    </CascadingValue>
    ...
            <ul>
                @for (int i = 0; i < MondayTasks.Count(); i++)
                {
                    var myIndex = i;
                    <li class="btn" @onclick="@(() => LoadTaskDetailsForTask(MondayTasks[myIndex].Id))">
                        <a role="button">
                            <h4>@MondayTasks[i].Name</h4>
                            <p>@MondayTasks[i].DeadlineDate.Date.ToShortDateString()</p>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                }
            </ul>
    ...

private async Task LoadTaskDetailsForTask(int taskId)
{
    SelectedTaskId = taskId;
    IsTaskDetailsVisible = true;
    await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("onScrollEvent");
}
public void RemoveTaskDetails()
{
    IsTaskDetailsVisible = false;
    StateHasChanged();
}
```

**SubComponent** (TaskDetails.razor)

```
@if (IsVisible)
{
    ...
            <div class="row">
                <h2 class="inner-div title">@taskDetails.Name</h2>
                <span class="closebtn" @onclick="()=> ToggleVisibility()">&times;</span>
            </div>

    //Display Information
}

...
[CascadingParameter]
public TaskList _Parent { get; set; }

protected async override void OnParametersSet()
{
    taskDetails = await _dbTasks.GetTasksDetails(TaskId);
    TaskItems = await _dbTasks.GetTasksItems(TaskId);
    this.StateHasChanged();
}

private void ToggleVisibility()
{
    _Parent.RemoveTaskDetails();
}
```

Comment: Can you share [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: @vernou I can, but I think it is a such broad question, that giving an example wouldn't help. Also, is not like I have a error in my code, but instead, probably, a wrong way of approaching the problem.

Comment: Maybe this tutorial can help : [Build a blazor todo list app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/build-a-blazor-app)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have

```
[Parameter] bool IsVisible  {get; set; }
private void ToggleVisibility()
{
    IsVisible = !IsVisible;
}
```

This is a pattern to avoid: Do not change a parameter from inside the Component.

You will have to add an EventCallback and change the IsTaskDetailsVisible on the main component.

Comment: That did it, thanks. Can you just check my updated question and see if that is an correct way to do it (and if not point me in the right direction) please?

Comment: I can't check right now but while Cascading the Parent is Ok it won't trigger a StateHasChanged on the Parent level. I'll add an EventCallback example later.

Comment: okay, thank you. Just to add, in case you didn't notice I added a `StateHasChanged()` manually.

Comment: O yes, I hadn't seen that. It will do the job.